# Twilio c# TwiML not dialing number. Saying it instead

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-twiml

I'm setting up masked calling. When I get the following TwiML response after calling the masked number, it isn't dialing the number that I'm specifying. It's just saying the number instead after saying the content of the `say`

Here is the TwiML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>Your call will be charged blah blah.</Say>
  <Dial action="http://mywebsite.com/Call/CallComplete" callerId="+441XXXXX">
    <Number>+44795XXXXX</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

And here is the c#

```
public static string TwiMLDial(string maskedNumber, string to, string actionURL)
{
  var response = new Twilio.TwiML.VoiceResponse();
  response.Say("Your call will be charged blah blah.");

  var dial = new Twilio.TwiML.Dial(action: actionURL, callerId: maskedNumber);
  dial.Number(to);
  response.Dial(dial);
  return response.ToString();
}
```

I'm using c# .Net core. And have the following in my startup.cs which may be relevant:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                // Add XML Content Negotiation
                config.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
                config.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerInputFormatter());
                config.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
            })
             .AddJsonOptions(options =>
             {
                 options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                 options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
             });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The issue is that your endpoint is returning the response with the type `text/plain` and Twilio takes that to mean, just read this out.

You need to set your response `Content-Type` to `text/xml` or `application/xml`.

I'm not a C# developer I'm afraid, but hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I am indeed returning a string in my controller.

Comment: Changed it to return with application/xml and it's all good now. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome, glad to have helped!